# How to pass multiple files as input to MapReduce?

Tags: mapreduce

I want to use two files as input to a MapReduce program. but using * doesn't work as a filename pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect working with input/ should do the trick. To get started try running the Wordcount example: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

At the end of this tutorial they explain you how to run the job (they run it on multiple dictionary files which reside in an input map).

EDIT: Also check this tutorial for using the distributed file system, you usually need your input files in the dfs..

Comment: Yes. input/ will read all files under input directory. However, what if it contains other irrelevant files too? In that case, using a file pattern is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

It works and it should work on your machine as well. Are you sure about the path you are giving? Is it **input/190*.txt** or **/input/190*.txt**. Please mind the **"/"**. Path without a / are assumed to be present inside the **/user** where as paths with a / are present directly under the root directory.

And it works with mv(or any other HDFS command for that matter) as well.

Comment: No, it isn't working for me. My input argument is `input/190*.txt` because `input` directory is in the current working directory. This is the usual way I perform other commands without pattern.

Comment: The files are stored in the path `/user/myname/input`. So I am using the path as `input/190*.txt`